# Where does mapViewDelegate get a value?

Tags: objective-c, tangram

In Tangram's current [source code](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es/tree/master/platforms/ios/framework/src) you can see that the TGMapView [has a mapViewDelegate](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es/blob/master/platforms/ios/framework/src/TGMapView.mm#L521) as a property. Where does this property get a value?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

---

**What I've tried**

I've used

```
grep -rnw 'tangram-es/platforms/ios/framework/src/' -e 'mapViewDelegate'
```

to find all the occurrences of the variable. That comes up with expressions, but not assignments.

I don't think 'mapViewDelegate' is special value that iOS deals with through the storyboard or other "for free" assignments.

My best lead so far is the `[self setup];` step in each init of TGMapView. At this step I'm getting lost following the thread.

Comment: `mapViewDelegate` is set in `viewDidLoad` in tangram-es/platforms/ios/demo/src/MapViewController.m

Comment: You are totally right. Perfect, thank you! You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapViewDelegate` is set in `viewDidLoad` in tangram-es/platforms/ios/demo/src/MapViewController.m